# Voltage-controlled pulse width modulator (PWM) LTC6992 accuracy

Tags: sensor, pwm, precision

I have to design a voltage sensor for sensing 4000 V highly precisely and for making the PWM. I was surveying the LTC6992. It is simple and quiet, easy to implement, but there is a problem with its accuracy. Accoring to its datasheet the accuracy changes from 3% to 4.9% which is so drastic for what I need. I tried to find a similar chip with a better accuracy (up to 1%) but I couldn't find any yet. Any suggestion?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need to convert to PWM? What's the relevance of the 4000 volts to your question?

Comment: I wonder what kind of solution you are attempting. You're referring to a voltage controlled PWM which has a 0V to 1V input. I believe, your biggest problem is to bring down your 4000V to a level that can be measured. Then, why are you trying to convert to PWM when an old-good ADC will do the job? Finally, please clarify your constraints because the word "precisely" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: The sensor that I want to make should measure up tp 4000V. Then I need to have a chip to generate PWM for activating a photodiode. I hope the photo helps explaining the issue better. The accuracy of the PWM generator is so important.

Comment: Note that `3% to 4.9%` should read `+/-3% to +/-4.9%`.  This means -3% to +3%, or 6% total, and likewise 9.8% worst-case.  I agree with Andy - why is PWM required?  Can a linear stage be used instead?  Consider something like this [linear IL300 Optocoupler](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83708/appnote50.pdf).  Very flat response and [isolated to 5300VAC](https://datasheet.octopart.com/IL300-F-X009T-Vishay-datasheet-13065703.pdf).  0.01% servo linearity.